# Getting a value of a function variable to GUI

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface

I'm creating a quite simple GUI.
Some parameters entered by the user are taken by a function which plots a diagram.
That functions uses another function to compute a value of let's say "d". Those functions are saved in different .m files.

How can I get that "d" out of that function and put it somewhere in the GUI after a button click (in edit text for instance)?

The problem is that I can't get d directly as it is stored in another file and I don't know the command to get it from the function.

Thanks for helping! I hope it's not to vague.

Comment: You can't just return the variable as an output argument and pass it that way?

Comment: Thank you very much!
Option B is what i really needed, although I hoped it would be possible without changing the code of the ABCFunction (adding "setappdata(0,'dInFunction',d)"). 
Anyway it works, thanks a million!

Comment: Voting up requires 15 reputation - I'm new here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the option provided by @chappjc is the best way to get your value. I propose another way which you might find helpful as well, using [setappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html?refresh=true) and getappdata. Those are used to store variables in some workspace (eg. base workspace or the workspace of a particular function) and can be used to share data between functions. In this example, I use the Matlab root i.e. 'base' workspace.

In the following code there are 2 functions, one called ABCFunction, which calculates d, and the function called ABCGUI, which is a simple GUI to demonstrate the point. Basically the user enters 3 values in 3 edit text boxes, and upon pressing the button, d is calculated through function 'ABCFunction', and the output is displayed in an editbox.

The way proposed by chappjc is called Option A and the option using setappdata/getappdata is Option B. You can comment the appropriate code in both function to play around and see how it works. The result is the same. So here they are:

**1)** ABC function

```
function d = ABCFunction(a,b,c)

%// Option A
d = a*b+c;

%//Option B
d = a*b+c; %// Does not change from Option A.
setappdata(0,'dInFunction',d); %// Assign the result, d, in a variable that you will call from your main GUI. See below.
end
```

**2)** ABCGui function

```
function ABCGui(~)

%  Create the GUI figure.
handles.figure = figure('Visible','on','Position',[360,500,300,285]);

handles.texta = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Enter a',...
    'Position',[50,140,60,15]);

handles.edita = uicontrol('Style','edit','String','',...
    'Position',[50,120,60,20]);


handles.textb = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Enter b',...
    'Position',[120,140,60,15]);

handles.editb = uicontrol('Style','edit','String','',...
    'Position',[120,120,60,20]);


handles.textc = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Enter c',...
    'Position',[190,140,60,15]);

handles.editc = uicontrol('Style','edit','String','',...
    'Position',[180,120,60,20]);

handles.Button = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Calculate d','Position',[50,60,80,15],'Callback',@PushbuttonCallback);

handles.textd = uicontrol('Style','text','String','d = a*b+c',...
    'Position',[80,90,80,15]);

handles.textResult = uicontrol('Style','text','String','',...
    'Position',[175,90,60,15]);

guidata(handles.figure,handles) %// Update handles structure.
%============================================================

    %// Setup callback of the pushbutton
    function PushbuttonCallback(~,~)

        handles = guidata(gcf); %// Retrieve handles structure

        A = str2num(get(handles.edita,'String'));
        B = str2num(get(handles.editb,'String'));
        C = str2num(get(handles.editc,'String'));

        %// Option A
        d = ABCFunction(A,B,C); %// Call the function and assign the output directly to a variable.

        %// Option B
        ABCFunction(A,B,C); %// Call the function and fetch the variable using getappdata.
        d = getappdata(0,'dInFunction');

        set(handles.textResult,'String',num2str(d));

    end
end
```

The GUI is quite simple and looks like the following:

[image]

As you can see it's much simpler to assign the variable to the function output. If it's not possible, you can go with Option B. Hope that helps!